# Gridview (Change Delete to another wording) C# 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my gridview we are in need of changing the wording from Delete to Remove.  Any ideas on how to do that?  This is what I have...

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="False" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="purchase_id" Visible="False" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `DeleteText`:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Remove" />
```

Is that all you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can aslo use Template Field, if you need any kind of customization in your grid. In this example I have change command field to template field. Changing makes it more flexible to use.

```
<Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="purchase_id" Visible="False" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <Itemtemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" text="Remove"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

OR 
In your case you can simply use  `DeleteText` as `<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Remove" />`